# HTML5 Video is not working in Safari , iPhone and iPad

Tags: html, ios, iphone, video, html5-video

the video working fine in all other devices and android but not even display in Safari , iPhone and iPad, i use all tags like playsinline and playsnline in camel case, but till facing problem and if i upload video on any server and used the url like: https://video.mp4 then it works fine. but static video like: video.mp4 not play even not show, only display a blank page here is my code:

```
<video width="100%" autoplay muted loop playsInline>
   <source src="cuted_preview.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
    
<video width="100%" autoplay muted loop playsinline>
   <source src="cuted_preview.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As it stands, it is impossible to determine what the potential cause of error is within your code, please update your question to provide more technical information e.g. your file structure and where the video is located.

Comment: Can you also share a link to the video if possible - it may be an issue with the server?